# Why does comparing a list and a tuple always return False

Tags: python

The title is it, really. Very unexpected. I'm wondering why this is the case. I'd have expected (4,3,2) == [4,3,2] to be True, but it isn't. If the language regarded them as not compatible types for comparison, it would throw an exception.

```
>>> (4,3,2) == [4,3,2]
False
>>> (4,3,2) == tuple([4,3,2])
True
>>> () == []
False
```

I guess the moral is that when comparing multiple values, explicitly convert to list or to tuple!

Comment: For the same reason that `1 == '1'` isn't true.

Comment: When does python ever give an error for checking equality of non-compatible objects? Perhaps you're confusing it with trying to order unorderable objects?

Comment: I don't think there are any types that `==` throws an exception for.  Everything is an object, and we can compare objects.

Comment: You can implement `__eq__` for an object. I think my question is, why does that implementation for list against tuple not cast one side to the other type before comparing, nor raise an exception for what is surely a bug in need of fixing nine times in ten?

Comment: See Patrich Haugh's comment. It's not just tuples and lists. It's the same behavior for sets, strings, Nonetype, Ranges..... there's no exceptions raised for any comparisons whatsoever unless it's one for which comparison has explicitly not been implemented.

Comment: ...and there is also no implicit type casting.